# SpringBootTest doesn't import local properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I am running full app test and would like to read in all of the properties for my app from `src/test/resources` but when I add the `@TestPropertySource` and locations, the app still fails to load.

In production, my config is hosted on an external server and I am able to successfully load the config for local testing with this in the boostrap.yml: `spring.cloud.config.uri: {pathToDevelopmentConfigServer}` However, when I remove that in favor of trying to read config locally, I can't get load the app.

My setup:
Test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:MyApp.yaml", "classpath:MyApp-test.yaml"})
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"default", "test"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyAppProperties.class})
public class MyAppTestClass {
  
  @Test
  public void myTest(){
    assertTrue(true); //dummy test just to have one for now
  }
}
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test-config")
@Validated
public class MyAppProperties {

  @NotNull
  private String myPropertyValue;
  
  @NotNull
  private Map<String, String> myPropertyMap;

  // Getters & Setters
}
```

Config file (MyApp-test.yaml):

```
test-config:
  myPropertyValue: "testValue"
  myPropertyMap:
    mapKey: "myMapTestValue"
```

However, when I try to run this, I get this error:

```
Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under '-test' to com.c.taylor.properties.MyAppProperties$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fd769f1a failed:

    Property: test-config.myPropertyValue
    Value: null
    Reason: must not be null

    Property: test-config.myPropertyMap
    Value: null
    Reason: must not be null


Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

I've read several docs about how to load properties into a SpringBootTest, but just haven't had any sort of luck.

Thanks in advance.

---

edit:
src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml file:

```
---
spring:
  application:
    name: MyApp
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: {pathToDevelopmentConfigServer}
      enabled: false
```

Comment: You may not need TestPropertySource here. Create simple 'application.yaml' in 'src/test/resources'. Remove all other yaml files and TestPropertySource annotation. It should work fine.

Comment: Removed @TestPropertySource and moved all config to the MyApp.yaml file in src/test/resources.  No change in behavior